# How to add a class to only the specifically clicked element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im looping over an object and displaying li tags and attaching a click handler.

Below that is a game component that displays further information.

Can someone help me with my logic and how to tell React to only add the class to the specific component related to the click.
 at

Currently when I click one element, all of the following game components open at the same time. I just want the one below to open.

Library Component

```
 class Library extends React.Component {

  state = {
    active: false
  };

  toggleClass = index => {
    let active = this.state.active;
    active = !active;
    this.setState({ active });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Game Library</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.props.games.map((game, index) => (
            <Fragment key={`${index}-${game.name}`}>
              <li
                key={`${index}-${game.gameId}`}
                onClick={() => this.toggleClass(index)}
              >
                {game.name}
              </li>
              <Game
                key={index}
                index={index}
                game={this.props.games[index]}
                active={this.state.active}
              />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Game Component

```
  class Game extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div
            key={this.props.index}
            className={this.props.active ? "show" : "hide"}
          >
            <p>{this.props.game.name}</p>
            <p>{this.props.game.gameId}</p>
            <a>Close</a>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a boolean `active` that you use for each `game`, you could use an object with a key for each `index` that indicates if that particular game is active.

**Example**

```
class Library extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: {}
  };

  toggleClass = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const active = { ...previousState.active };
      active[index] = !active[index];
      return { active };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h2>Game Library</h2>
        <ul>
          {this.props.games.map((game, index) => (
            <Fragment key={`${index}-${game.name}`}>
              <li
                key={`${index}-${game.gameId}`}
                onClick={() => this.toggleClass(index)}
              >
                {game.name}
              </li>
              <Game
                key={index}
                index={index}
                game={game}
                active={this.state.active[index]}
              />
            </Fragment>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect. I was breaking down what you did keeping an eye on my state and I realised that the state was growing and growing with each index. Would it be beneficial to use setState on each click and clear out the previous click? EDIT: just realised this will stop you from closing a previous click.

Comment: @Darren Great! Yes, the `active` object will be empty at first, but will grow to a max of one key per game, if you click on all of them.

Comment: @Darren Did you only want one game to be open at a time? Maybe you could create a new question if you can't figure it out?